# Parse: How to sign-in / sign-up users only with an email address like Medium.com? (no passwords)

Tags: authentication, parse-platform, passwords, email-verification

I want to allow users to both sign in and sign up only with an email address and without entering passwords using Parse in a similar way to how Medium does it where an email is sent with a deep-link that logs in the user into the IOS app without a password. How can I do this on Parse?

Comment: Have the app provide a password to sign up/in.  Have the app send emailVerifications and restrict function only to those who have been verified.

Comment: but what happens if user logs out and needs to log back in again OR deletes app and reinstalls again? how will app know on second time around what password to use log in a registered user?

Comment: The app provides the password on any login.